# RxCocoa - prevent multiple view controller pushes when there's lag

Tags: ios, uitableview, rx-swift, reactive, rx-cocoa

As is the case with both Reactive and non-Reactive iOS projects alike, if you have a UI element (e.g. a button or a table view cell that is being selected) that pushes a view controller onto the navigation stack, if there's lag for some reason (especially on older devices) repetitive taps can result in duplicate pushes and thus bad UX.

Normally you could disable the element after the first tap.

For example:

```
@IBAction func myButtonTap() { 
    button.isEnabled = false
    doTheRestOfTheAction()
}
```

I am relatively new to RxSwift. I am trying to figure out an appropriate Reactive way to implement this to fix a few bugs in my app where views get pushed repetitively.

Some thoughts:

Could use `debounce` or `throttle` but seems like a bandaid and won't necessarily fix every situation.

I'm currently thinking that the best way is to dispose of the subscription once the expected event has occurred.

```
let disposable = tableView.rx.itemSelected
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] indexPath in 
        self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MySegueIdentifier", sender: self)
    })

...

func prepareForSegue() {
    myDisposable.dispose()
    finishPrepareForSegue()
}
```

Although if you want to unsubscribe inside the subscribe block, the compiler complains about using a variable inside its own initial value, which makes sense. I suppose there are workarounds but I wonder, is there a better way? Maybe a Reactive operator I'm missing?

Tried searching around for similar examples but the results were limited.

Thanks

EDIT: perhaps the `takeUntil` operator?

[Possibly relevant SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35912089/1032372).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the only solution, but this seems to be working well at least for the case of pushing upon table view selection. It uses the `takeUntil` operator to stop the events

```
myTableView.rx.itemSelected
.takeUntil(self.rx.methodInvoked(#selector(viewWillDisappear)))
.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] indexPath in
    self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MySegueIdentifier", sender: self)
)}
.dispose(by: self.myDisposeBag)
```

Although note that if you can return to view controller then you'd have to resubscribe, perhaps by moving the subscription to `viewDidAppear`. Maybe there's a more efficient method though that doesn't require re-subscription.

Another option is `take(1)` instead of `takeUntil(…)`, but it would still require re-subscription upon returning to the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I see a lot at my company is the use of Rx's `Variable` that is something like `loginInFlight` which is a `Variable<boolean>`. This is defaulted to false and when the command is run to login we flip it to true. This boolean is also tied to the login button so once the user clicks login any subsequent clicks do not do anything. You could implement this wherever a user can click on something to change screens to make sure there isn't already a call / event in progress.

We follow MVVM so here's an example based on that. I tried to only show the barebones down below it so hopefully everything still makes sense below.

#### LoginViewController

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...

        // This commandAvailable is what I was talking about above
        viewModel?
            .loginCommandAvailable
            .subscribe(onNext: {[unowned self] (available: Bool) in
                 self.signInButton.isEnabled = available
            })
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

        signInButton.rx.tap
            .map {
                // Send Login Command
                return viewModel?.loginCommand()
            }.subscribe(onNext: { (result: LoginResult)
                // If result was successful we can send the user to the next screen
            }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }
}
```

#### LoginViewModel

```
enum LoginResult: Error {
    case success
    case failure
}

class LoginViewModel {
    private let loginInFlight = Variable<Bool>(false)

    private var emailAddressProperty = Variable<String>("")
    var emailAddress: Driver<String> {
        return emailAddressProperty
            .asObservable()
            .subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(queue: DispatchQueue.global()))
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: "")
    }

    ...

    var loginCommandAvailable: Observable<Bool> {
        // We let the user login if login is not currently happening AND the user entered their email address 
        return Observable.combineLatest(emailAddressProperty.asObservable(), passwordProperty.asObservable(), loginInFlight.asObservable()) {
            (emailAddress: String, password: String, loginInFlight: Bool) in
                return !emailAddress.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty && !loginInFlight
        }
    }

    func loginCommand() -> Driver<LoginResult> {
        loginInFlight.value = true

        // Make call to login
        return authenticationService.login(email: emailAddressProperty.value, password: passwordProperty.value)
        .map { result -> LoginResult in
            loginInFlight.value = false
            return LoginResult.success
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit For Toggling Command based on Availability

#### LoginViewController

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...

        // This commandAvailable is what I was talking about above
        viewModel?
            .loginCommandAvailable
            .subscribe(onNext: {[unowned self] (available: Bool) in
                 self.signInButton.isEnabled = available
            })
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

        signInButton.rx.tap
            .map {
                return viewModel?.loginCommandAvailable
            }.flatmap { (available: Bool) -> Observable<LoginResult>
                // Send Login Command if available
                if (available) {
                    return viewModel?.loginCommand()
                }
            }.subscribe(onNext: { (result: LoginResult)
                // If result was successful we can send the user to the next screen
            }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is useful and thank you very much for it, but I don't see how it answers the question. Enabling a button after something has happened is not the same as preventing future events after something has happened.

Comment: @shim you said "if there's lag for some reason (especially on older devices) repetitive taps can result in duplicate pushes and thus bad UX.". Using a Variable to toggle commands availability will prevent the "repetitive taps".

Comment: Well, in the particular case I'm working on I don't actually want to disable a button, but rather stop listening to cell selection events. I suppose I could disable the table view but that doesn't really seem like the correct solution.

Comment: You can just "disable" the command that is called on the selection of the cell. If you're trying to find a way to handle two cell selections that go to different screens then I think you really need to just prevent the latter from going onto the stack. I'll add a blurb at the bottom of my answer to have the commandAvailable w/ command mapping instead of disabling the button.

Comment: Well it's calling `performSegue` but I suppose it could be modified to call some intermediate function or I could use `shouldPerformSegue` or something.

Comment: Just thought of another idea, you could use something like MBProgressHUD (or some other loading indicator) for when you are preparing to segue to another screen. That way on slower devices you have something preventing the user from accessing the rest of the elements and on faster devices I believe that library will not show the loading indicator if the task is quick enough.